# How to write a script for automatically uploading/inserting images which are saved in team drive?

Tags: google-sheets, image-uploading, google-drive-shared-drive

I have to insert images to google drive spreadsheet on the daily basis.  The image is saved in the specific folder of team drive.  Want to write a script so that the images can be inserted automatically once I press the "Macro Button".

The name-formatting of images is random (but can be renamed like 20190122US,20190122ASIA, let us assume this). For example, they are saved under team drive path:team drive\Daily\Testing.  The type of file is GIF image. I have tried the below code, but can only insert the picture from Internet with url.  I think the images in the team drive has different url or even don't have public url.  Some people talks of Google Drive REST API v3. but I couldn't find it.

```
function insertImageOnSpreadsheet() {
  // URL of spreadsheet.
var SPREADSHEET_URL = '--';
  // Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet.  
  var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet 1';  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('--');
  var binaryData = response.getContent();

  // Insert the image in cell E6.  
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(binaryData, 'image/png', 'MyImageName');
  sheet.insertImage(blob, 5, 1);
}
```

I expect to insert the pictures in team drive.  ideally, the pictures can be inserted and be moved into a achieved folder in the same saved path:team drive\Daily\Testing\achieved files.

Comment: Welcome Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question. There is much information that you have not included. 1) Are the images already uploaded to the "\Daily\Testing" folder, or do you need to do that also? 2) Please explain why you are referencing another spreadsheet 3) what is it that you expect to retrieve with `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('--');`, 4) are you the owner of the spreadsheets, folders and files?

Comment: From the Apps Script Issue Tracker: [Insert Image Blob into Spreadsheet](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760259); This may be relevant to you. The most recent entry is Jan 2019.

Comment: Ignore REST API v3 - it's irrelevant. There's an expectation that you **search and research** before you ask a question. Have you looked at [File-Open dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs), the [Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/) tool and [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)? Have you searched on updating sheets from a callback? Re-read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question with details of your research.